# How to Serialize object to byte array with compact bytes in java

Tags: java, serialization

For example, I have a class that has short, byte, int type member variable.

```
class A{
    short a;
    byte b;
    int c;
}
```

If I serialize or convert to byte array, the Array is unexpected value.

if values like,

```
A a = new A();
a.a = 3;
a.b = 0x02;
a.c = 15;
```

then, I expect its bytes as,

```
00 03 02 00 00 00 0F
```

So... How to Serialize Object like that?

It needs my socket server... other language

Comment: What values do you receive after serialization?

Comment: long, int, short, byte, float, double ... normal values.

Comment: No, question is about which exactly bytes do you receive output?

Comment: How do you serialize it now? And what does that produce instead of the expected output?

Comment: my server receive bytes data. but I don't have sample. I just want to know how to make the object compact byte array

Comment: I check each byte and split bytes are enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a byte array you can do this. However if you are using something like DataOutputStream it's best to just call writeInt, writeShort, ...

```
A a = new A();
a.a = 3;
a.b = 0x02;
a.c = 15;

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(7).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
bb.putShort(a.a).put(a.b).putInt(a.c).flip();
byte[] buffer = bb.array();
for (byte b : buffer)
    System.out.printf("%02X ", b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get all [`fields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) in the class, and loop them to convert to an array of bytes.

If all your fields are [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) (i.e. not references nor `boolean`), you can convert and collect them to a `List` of `Byte` as follows:

```
List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Field field : A.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    // Do something else if field is not a Number
    // ...

    // Otherwise, convert and collect into list
    Number n = (Number) field.get(a);
    int size = n.getClass().getDeclaredField("BYTES").getInt(null);
    IntStream.range(0, size)
        .mapToObj(i -> (byte) (n.longValue() >> 8*(size-i-1)))
        .forEach(b -> list.add(b));
}
```